# Problem with rendering and using rendered view

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, artifacts

When i render an object (the basic cube) it has transparent areas dotted over it. Also when i'm in rendered view there are strange coloured specs on the cube. I am using the latest version of blender as of now, if you have any questions about my settings let me know :)

[image]

thats the result when rendering the image.[image]

here is what it looks like in rendered view.[image]

and here too.

Comment: This looks like an issue with your graphics driver or unsupported hardware. Try to update your GPU driver and check if that resolves the issue. Also make sure that your hardware fulfills the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/), especially the ones for the GPU.

Comment: is there not a way to use cpu rendering instead of gpu rendering?

Comment: For the final render you can choose between CPU and GPU rendering for Cycles, [Eevee always uses the GPU since it's based on OpenGL](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/EEVEE#Limitations). For the viewport rendering you need a suitable GPU as well.